# Why is this text not updating?

Tags: javascript, html, text, auto-update

I've created a simple script that randomly opens sites from a list. I've recently tried to add a feature that enables users to choose the wait (in milliseconds) between the open and close of each page. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>



  <head>

    <title>Smokescreen</title>

  </head>

  <body align="center" style="font-family:monospace">

    <h2 align="center" style="font-family:monospace">
      SmokeScreen
    </h2>

    <h3 align="center" style="font-family:monospace">
      SmokeScreen is a JavaScript program that opens a random site every 3 seconds,
    </h3>

    <h3 align="center" style="font-family:monospace">
      to create a "smokescreen" over your browser history, preventing anyone from [easily] finding your information.
    </h3>

    <h4 align="center" style="font-family:monospace">To exit, close the original window that has the text "Smokescreen" in the title.</h4>


    <p align="center" style="font-family:monospace">

      <a href="github.com/keeganjk/smokescreen" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Source Code / Learn More</a>
      <br />

      <div style="width: 300px; border: 25px solid #800000; margin:0 auto; font-family:monospace;" align="center">

        <h4 align="center" style="font-family:monospace">Milliseconds to wait before closing page:</h4>
        <h4 id="one" align="center" style="font-family:monospace"></h4>
        <button onclick="millisecs = prompt('New time to wait (in milliseconds)?'); if ( isNaN(milliseconds) ) {millisecs = millisecsBackup} else {millisecsBackup = millisecs} document.getElementById('one').innerHTML = millisecs;" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Set Wait Time</button>
        <br />
        <br />

      </div>
      <br />

      <div style="margin:0 auto; font-family:monospace" align="center">

        <button onclick="getRandom(0, list.length, millisecs);" style="font-family:monospace" align="center">Start!</button>

      </div>

    </p>


  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
      var millisecs = 3000;
      var millisecsBackup = 3000;
      document.getElementById("one").innerHTML = millisecs;
  </script>

  </body>



</html>
```

For some reason, the text in the `h4` with the `id` of `one` isn't updating when I type in different numbers. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Extract the code from your button that is getting the user input into a function. Then when the button is clicked execute that function. This will allow you to debug your function.

Comment: You should learn to separate both style *(CSS)* and functionality *(JavaScript)* from your HTML, and use external scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking `if (isNaN(milliseconds))` but you called your variable `millisecs` so it is throwing an error.

If you're using a modern browser, try opening the developer tools (F12 on windows / CMD+OPT+i on mac) and checking the console.

Also please look into moving your inline styles / onclicks to `<style>` and `<script>` tags :)

Comment: I thought about doing that, but then it wasn't compatible for some browsers; some people on GitHub told me to expand the compatibility, so I guess I, "brute-forced" my way to compatibility... ;)